# How to bind an EF6 model object to a list of name-value pairs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

How can I automatically bind a list of name-value pairs to an EF6 model object to avoid having to explicitly assign every field manually? The code below is a console application, not MVC.

(I am importing data from an Excel spreadsheet to a database-first EF model. Currently I am accessing the cell values using the column number. I would rather look up the column heading and use that to bind against the corresponding contact field.)

```
 Contact contact = new Contact();

 contact.ModelID             = Model.ModelID;
 contact.Email               = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  1]);
 contact.CreatedByID         = Convert.ToInt32(      sheet.Cells[rowNum,  2]);
 contact.CreatedOn           = Convert.ToDateTime(   sheet.Cells[rowNum,  3]);
 contact.CategoryID          = Convert.ToInt32(      sheet.Cells[rowNum,  4]);
 contact.Company             = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  5]);
 contact.Phone               = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  6]);
 contact.Department          = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  7]);
 contact.OrganizationCode    = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  8]);
 contact.GivenName           = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum,  9]);
 contact.FamilyName          = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 10]);
 contact.Street              = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 11]);
 contact.PostalBox           = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 12]);
 contact.Town                = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 13]);
 contact.StateRegion         = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 14]);
 contact.PostalCode          = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 15]);
 contact.Country             = Convert.ToString(     sheet.Cells[rowNum, 16]);

 db.Contacts.Add(contact);
```

Comment: I believe this library would work? https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: I've had a lot of success reading the Excel spreadsheet directly using EPPlus and was hoping not to have to go via CSV.